# How to create only subclasses tables in hibernate (@Transient @Entity)

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, superclass, transient

I have a superclass Model

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractModel implements Model {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
}
```

and some it's inheritors like PostModel

```
@Entity
public class PostModel extends AbstractModel {
    private String header;
    private String content;
}
```

I want to store only inheritors in database, but all they should have the same identified declared in superclass. Is it possible to don't create table for superclass, using hibernate inheritance? Is it right descision to solve this problem? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Use @MappedSuperclass for AbstractModel (in your case).
See 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro002.htm
for more on entity inheritance